# is there a built in "spell checker" for syntax in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, settings, spell-checking

if so, how can i activate it? 
I'm using c.

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spell checker for syntax"?

Comment: something that highlights syntax mistakes, like when you forget a bracket or you misspell some parameter...

Answer (score 1):

For [Spell checking](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce/) and [Productivity Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)